# Collecting data with Parse::RecDescent

Tags: perl, parse-recdescent

I have a list of strings (30,000+) which are a collection of statements. Logically, [`Parse::RecDescent`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Parse::RecDescent) is the tool to use to parse the string to gather the data, but I just can't get my head round the construction of the grammar specification.

The following code is building a big list of blessed *nodes*, however I just can't figure out how to actually create a more useful data-structure
(All I want are the `Year`, `Vol` & `Iss` values)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Parse::RecDescent;
use Data::Dumper;

my $string1 = '2006 - v. 1 (1-2), 2007 - v. 2 (1-4), 2008 - v. 3 (1-4), 2009 - v. 4 (1-4), 2010 - v. 5 (1-4), 2011 - v. 6 (1-2), 2012 - v. 7 (1, 4), 2013/2014 - v. 8 (1-4), 2014 - v. 9 (1, 3)';
my $string2 = 'v.35(1,2),v.36(1,2),v.33(1,2),v.34(1,2),v.39(1,2),v.37(1,2),v.38(1,2),v.43(1,2),v.42(1,2),v.41(1,2),v.40(1,2),v.22(),v.23(),v.24(),v.25(1),v.26(),v.27(),v.28(1,2),v.29(1,2),v.3(),v.2(1,2),v.1(1,2),v.30(),v.7(),v.6(),v.32(1,2),v.5(),v.4(),v.31()';
my $string3 = '1820/1825 - v. 1 (1-2), 1821/1825 - v. 2 (3-4), 1821/1826 - v. 3 (5-6), 1821 - v. 4 (7-8), 1822 - v. 5 (9-10), 1823 - v. 6 (11-12), 1823 - v. 7 (13-14), 1823 - v. 8 (15-16), 1824 - v. 9 (17-18)';

my $data = {}; # Edit: Added hash-ref to show alternate testing
my $grammar = q {
   <autotree> 
     Holdings  : Node(s /,/) 
     Node      : When(?) Volume Issue { $data->{ $item{when} } = [ $item{Vol}, $item{Iss} ] } # Edit: Action Added - This was one option I tried
     When      : Years | Year { $arg[0] = $item{When} } 
     Years     : Year '/' Year
     Year      : /\\d{4}/  { $item[1] } # Edit: Action Added - This was another option I tried
     Volume    : /v\\.\\s*/ Vol { $arg[1] = $item{Vol} } # Edit: Add commet "This was blindly flailing to work out how to get variable data
     Vol       : /\\d+/
     Issue     : /\\s*\(/ Iss ')' { $arg[2] = $item{Iss} }
     Iss       : /[\\d+\\-\\,]*/ 
     };

my $parser = Parse::RecDescent->new($grammar);

foreach my $string ( ($string1, $string2, $string3) ) {
  $string =~ s/\s+\-\s+//g;
  print "$string\n";
  my $output = $parser->Holdings($string);
  print Dumper $output;
}
```

On a side-note, how do I write the grammar statement so I don't need the substitution in the loop?

Comment: You can do this in the actions for `When`, `Volume`, and `Issue`; simply add the values to your own data structure there. Be aware that "action[s] execute within a special namespace belonging to the active parser, so care must be taken in correctly qualifying variable names."

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot - I gather that from the Rec::ParseDescent documentation..... but I just can't figure it out (everything I try either gives me just one piece of data, or nothing)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show exactly what you tried and the results you got. At a guess, you did something like `{ $foo = "bar" }` instead of `{ $main::foo = "bar" }`

Comment: Are the actions like `$arg[0] = $item{When}` etc. intended to export the values that you require? Do you realise that `@arg` and `%arg` are used by the parser itself, and shouldn't be manipulated directly like that? Also, you would need to declare a *package* variable in your main program and write to that using fully-qualified identifiers as **ThisSuitIsBlackNot** has described

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`make_parser.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Parse::RecDescent qw( );

my $grammar = <<'__END_OF_GRAMMAR__';
   {
      use strict;
      use warnings;
   }

   parse    : Holdings /\Z/            { $item[1] }

   Holdings : Node(s /,/)             #{ $item[-1] }

   Node     : When /-?/ Node_          { [ $item[1], @{$item[3]} ] }
            | Node_                    { [ undef,    @{$item[1]} ] }
   Node_    : Volume Issue             { [ $item[1], $item[2] ] }

   When     : Year When_[ $item[1] ]  #{ $item[-1] }
   When_    : '/' Year                 { $arg[0] . '/' . $item[2] }
            |                          { $arg[0] }
   Year     : /\d{4}/                 #{ $item[-1] }

   Volume   : /v\.\s*/ /\d+/          #{ $item[-1] }

   Issue    : '(' /[^)]*/ ')'          { $item[2] =~ s/\s//gr }

__END_OF_GRAMMAR__

Parse::RecDescent->Precompile($grammar, 'Grammar')
   or die("Bad grammar\n");
```

`a.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Grammar qw( );

#$::RD_TRACE = 1;

my $parser = Grammar->new();

while (<DATA>) {
   chomp;

   my $recs = $parser->parse($_)
      or do { warn("Bad data at line $.\n");
              next;
            };

   print("For: $_\n");
   for my $rec (@$recs) {
      printf("   %s | %s | %s\n",
         defined($rec->[0]) ? $rec->[0] : '[undef]',
         $rec->[1],
         $rec->[2],
      );
   }
}

__DATA__
2006 - v. 1 (1-2), 2007 - v. 2 (1-4), 2008 - v. 3 (1-4), 2009 - v. 4 (1-4), 2010 - v. 5 (1-4), 2011 - v. 6 (1-2), 2012 - v. 7 (1, 4), 2013/2014 - v. 8 (1-4), 2014 - v. 9 (1, 3)
v.35(1,2),v.36(1,2),v.33(1,2),v.34(1,2),v.39(1,2),v.37(1,2),v.38(1,2),v.43(1,2),v.42(1,2),v.41(1,2),v.40(1,2),v.22(),v.23(),v.24(),v.25(1),v.26(),v.27(),v.28(1,2),v.29(1,2),v.3(),v.2(1,2),v.1(1,2),v.30(),v.7(),v.6(),v.32(1,2),v.5(),v.4(),v.31()
1820/1825 - v. 1 (1-2), 1821/1825 - v. 2 (3-4), 1821/1826 - v. 3 (5-6), 1821 - v. 4 (7-8), 1822 - v. 5 (9-10), 1823 - v. 6 (11-12), 1823 - v. 7 (13-14), 1823 - v. 8 (15-16), 1824 - v. 9 (17-18)
```

Output:

```
$ perl make_parser.pl

$ perl a.pl
For: 2006 - v. 1 (1-2), 2007 - v. 2 (1-4), 2008 - v. 3 (1-4), 2009 - v. 4 (1-4), 2010 - v. 5 (1-4), 2011 - v. 6 (1-2), 2012 - v. 7 (1, 4), 2013/2014 - v. 8 (1-4), 2014 - v. 9 (1, 3)
   2006 | 1 | 1-2
   2007 | 2 | 1-4
   2008 | 3 | 1-4
   2009 | 4 | 1-4
   2010 | 5 | 1-4
   2011 | 6 | 1-2
   2012 | 7 | 1,4
   2013/2014 | 8 | 1-4
   2014 | 9 | 1,3
For: v.35(1,2),v.36(1,2),v.33(1,2),v.34(1,2),v.39(1,2),v.37(1,2),v.38(1,2),v.43(1,2),v.42(1,2),v.41(1,2),v.40(1,2),v.22(),v.23(),v.24(),v.25(1),v.26(),v.27(),v.28(1,2),v.29(1,2),v.3(),v.2(1,2),v.1(1,2),v.30(),v.7(),v.6(),v.32(1,2),v.5(),v.4(),v.31()
   [undef] | 35 | 1,2
   [undef] | 36 | 1,2
   [undef] | 33 | 1,2
   [undef] | 34 | 1,2
   [undef] | 39 | 1,2
   [undef] | 37 | 1,2
   [undef] | 38 | 1,2
   [undef] | 43 | 1,2
   [undef] | 42 | 1,2
   [undef] | 41 | 1,2
   [undef] | 40 | 1,2
   [undef] | 22 |
   [undef] | 23 |
   [undef] | 24 |
   [undef] | 25 | 1
   [undef] | 26 |
   [undef] | 27 |
   [undef] | 28 | 1,2
   [undef] | 29 | 1,2
   [undef] | 3 |
   [undef] | 2 | 1,2
   [undef] | 1 | 1,2
   [undef] | 30 |
   [undef] | 7 |
   [undef] | 6 |
   [undef] | 32 | 1,2
   [undef] | 5 |
   [undef] | 4 |
   [undef] | 31 |
For: 1820/1825 - v. 1 (1-2), 1821/1825 - v. 2 (3-4), 1821/1826 - v. 3 (5-6), 1821 - v. 4 (7-8), 1822 - v. 5 (9-10), 1823 - v. 6 (11-12), 1823 - v. 7 (13-14), 1823 - v. 8 (15-16), 1824 - v. 9 (17-18)
   1820/1825 | 1 | 1-2
   1821/1825 | 2 | 3-4
   1821/1826 | 3 | 5-6
   1821 | 4 | 7-8
   1822 | 5 | 9-10
   1823 | 6 | 11-12
   1823 | 7 | 13-14
   1823 | 8 | 15-16
   1824 | 9 | 17-18
```

Comment: OK - I have **NO** idea how this works, but it does!  I'll spend some time removing & and replacing actions to see what impact that has.  (and the pre-complied Grammar file... ##WOW## !! )

Comment: A rule returns the last item. If that last item is a code block, it returns the value returned by that code block. (The trailing `{ $item[-1] }` are all commented out since they are redundant.)

Comment: I had to change `Issue` so your first line would match (since some of the issues had spaces in them). But I remove all spaces from the issue before returning it. /// The dash issue you were asking about was solved by adding `/-?/` between `When` and `Volume`. I had to restructure a little to only accept `-` when `When` was present. /// `When` could be a single regex. /// `/\Z/` makes sure errors there's nothing past the end of the string. Without it, all string will match by ignoring everything after the first error. /// Finally, `<<'...'` means you don't need to escape anything